# How can I use CanCanCan's `can?` method inside a view component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, view-components

As best I can tell, CanCanCan's `can?` method is available to normal views in Rails but not view components by default. What is the appropriate way to include the `can?` method in my view components? I already have my `app/models/ability.rb` file set up. In my other views I'm using `can?(:create, Post.new(project: @project))` but would love to use this in my `Header::HeaderComponent` view component as well.

I know I can add `include CanCan::Ability` within my component class but that doesn't seem right as it doesn't appear to make use of the rules I have defined in my ability class or have access to the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's about implement same way like [in the gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/a1e9a082b2dc2458e83ff95aa0506ad7a2069e96/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L342-L386)

```rb
def can?(*args)
  current_ability.can?(*args)
end

def cannot?(*args)
  current_ability.cannot?(*args)
end

def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= ::Ability.new(current_user)
end
```

Of course you need somehow pass current user to your component. Official guidelines suggest [such way](https://viewcomponent.org/guide/conditional_rendering.html)

```rb
class Header::HeaderComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  attr_reader :current_user

  def initialize(current_user:)
    @current_user = current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ViewComponent`s you can always delegate methods to helpers.
Your `can?` and `cannot?` methods are helpers. Therefore you can simply:

```rb
class Header::HeaderComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  delegate :can?, :cannot?, to: :helpers
end
```

of course you should do the same with any other helper method that you need.
I usually like to follow the pattern of having an ApplicationComponent that any other component inherits from.

```rb
class ApplicationComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  delegate :can?, :cannot?, to: :helpers
end

class Header::HeaderComponent < ApplicationComponent

end
```